# Make the user package point to somewhere else with sublime text

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets

I'm using Sublime text, and I'm sharing some snippets with coworkers. I would like to be abble to directly make sublime text go to this folder to find the snippets.

Do you know any good ways of doing it ?

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer,I'm on a mac on OS X Mountain Lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create a share folder with your team (say `/mnt/shared/snippets`)
- symlink that folder to your Sublime  folder
  `ln -s /mnt/shared/snippets "~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/User/"`
- restart Sublime and it should pick up the snippets